# Iptables Forwarding from one ip1:port1 to other ip2:port2

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

We are in middle of this unusual situation where we are trying to connect to Kafka Brokers in AWS but we can't access them through our DC directly.But we can use an endpoint(putting the brokers behind a NLB) that can go out to AWS from our DC.
What we are thinking is somehow we can modify the IPtables and redirect the traffic to that endpoint whenever anyone tries to hit the broker ip.On a high level we are sitting in our internal DC with two external addresses:addr1:port1 and addr2:port2, we can access/telnet to the second one so we want to redirect all traffic to this from addr1:port1.

We tried the following PREROUTING and POSTROUTING rules:
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d addr1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9094 -j DNAT --to-destination addr2:36379
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d addr2 --dport 36379 -j SNAT --to-source addr1:9094`
But no luck, are we missing something here? We should be able to telnet to the first address(addr1) once this forwarding configuration is done, shouldn't we?

Comment: You could get likely many answers from people knowing iptables well. But only a few people know kafka well. I suggest to detail much more clearly, what do you want on the TCP level, ideally the best would be if you would entirely miss kafka. If I understand you well, you want probably a bidirectional TCP connection between two machines, both of them behind different NATs what you can't easily change. Do I understand you well? If yes, you probably can't do that with iptables on a reliable way. But you can do it with the help of a third host and VPN.

Comment: @peterhsaysreinstateMonica Yes, you are correct.This has to be a bidirectional TCP connection but I was assuming this can be taken care by the SNAT or MASQUERADE thing.Anyway if we ignore the bidirectional part, we still are unable to have one way connection like after having this forwarding we can telnet to first address and it should go through as we can do the same using the second one.Anyway this is no longer a blocker but still a good exercise that I think would be helpful to others also :)

Comment: You can likely set up UDP-based communication with OpenVPN. You need to set up both the local and the remote ports on both sides. Then you will have a network interface where you can communicate. It will be hard and bug-prone, but you have at least a chance.

Comment: Hmm will look into this.By the way, what's wrong with the above approach? On a high level it appears to be just redirecting traffic from one ip:port to other ip2:port2 which should be easily doable using IPtables.

Comment: If I understand you well, you want to convert the incoming side of a tcp handshake to an outgoing side and vice versa. It is impossible, it won't be TCP any more ( -> no TCP-level packet altering solution, incl. iptables, can to that). It requires some extension to the TCP protocol, or a more complex protocol in which tcp can be embedded.

Comment: Correct, but I can see that IPtables have this -p parameter for protocol and it supports  tcp, udp and icmp.In fact that's the first reason which tempted me to try IPtables.Are we missing something here?

Comment: Yes, but you can't mediate a TCP handshake between two NATted machines with packet altering on a way, that the protocol remains TCP. It would only possible on a way that it doesn't remain TCP any more. I see some chance that I missed something, or you can circumvent the restriction on some way. And I don't want to pour cold water on your wishes. In a professional environment, the solution would be the reconfiguration of the AWS firewall to allow this connection, or utilizing a VPN for the task. But, you can play as you wish and if you have some idea, I will help as I can.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time.We have resolved this in a more cleaner way by updating the property "advertised.listeners" in Kafka brokers(nodes).It was nice discussing with you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do bidirectional TCP communications beside two different systems, if both are behind a NAT what you can't control and it don't help you.

It is because setting TCP ports is typically giving to some program, in some configuration file, an IP and a port value. It is easy to forward the incoming packets to an ip/port to another ip/port.

However, in the case of the TCP, much more things are happening:

- A connection request packet is sent
- It is acknowledged by the server with another packet
- The client sends its first data

Thus, while the TCP communication is symmetric, the TCP handshake *is not*. Thus, simple packet altering/forwarding can't convert an outgoing TCP request to an incoming one. Not only that there is no iptables module for that, it is *impossible even by the protocol*.

Note, the firewall of AWS machines is typically not completely chanceless to configure, it is only harder as it seems.

The problem of connecting systems where both are behind NATs, happened first time in the development of various peer-to-peer protocols. For example, many bittorrent clients *can* communicate to each other even if both sides are behind NATs. This is a possible research direction for you in the future.

However, a business solution would be one of these:

1. To configure their firewall (yes, I know, all my customers need a battle to finally do it. Sometimes they can do it only by deleting the whole machine. *But it can be done.*)
2. Connect both of them to a third machine with a VPN.
3. Not using AWS et al (I personally would prefer this, but often we need to adapt)